# Is it possible to change specific text color inside a string name stored in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, string

Weird request, I know, but for special reasons, is it possible to change the color of text inside a strings.xml string?  For example, I want the question text to be a specific color.  Text appears within a DialogFragment when the user clicks a help button.

`<string name="vendor_alert_text">Question 1?  Answer.  Questions 2?  Answer.  Question 3?  Answer</string>`

```
public class CustomerHelpDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertBuilder.setTitle(R.string.help_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.customer_alert_text)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Empty to close the dialog
                }
            });

    return alertBuilder.create();
}}
```

[image]

Comment: So where does this text appear? In a `TextView` where all the text should be blue or in a `TextView` where there is a mix of colors? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Oh sorry for not clarifying, text appears within a DialogFragment when the user clicks a help button.  Updated post with code.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/42c6250/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/strings.xml#25).

Comment: Awesome you rock!  Have a great week friend.  Found this too https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it its.

`<string name="concordoTermosEPolitica">Concordo com os <font color='#303f9f'>Termos de Uso</font> e a <font color='#303f9f'>Política de Privacidade.</font></string>`

This is an example o use.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV4Oa.jpg)

The important is `<font color='#303f9f'>WORDS</font>`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to change your text color within strings.xml, you just use android:textColor tag for TextView which will show your text.

With your DialogFragment you may use any custom layout, within it you can set any color you want for your TextViews:

```
    <string name="dialog_1">Dialog 1</string>
<string name="dialog_2">Dialog 2</string>
<string name="message_text">Text of your message</string>
<string name="yes">Yes</string>
<string name="no">No</string>
<string name="maybe">Maybe</string>
```

*

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" //ANY COLOUR YOU WANT
    android:text="@string/message_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/yes">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/no">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMaybe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/maybe">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
    public class Dialog1 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setTitle("Title!");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog1, null);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btnNo).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btnMaybe).setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 1: " + ((Button) v).getText());
    dismiss();
  }

  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 1: onDismiss");
  }

  public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 1: onCancel");
  }
}
```